# Include new files in hg diff patch

Tags: mercurial

How can I add a new file to mercurial diff patch ? I can't seem to find any information in the man pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but, if you are using Mercurial to generate a diff patch, the way to include new files you want to add to a repo is by marking the new files as part of the repo by using the hg `add` command and then doing the `diff`.

```
hg add newfile
hg diff > my.patch
```